# Xcode 5.1.1 - ARC project not showing error in certain files for using Release and Autorelease

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, automatic-ref-counting

I have got an Xcode 5.1.1 iOS project. I presume the project was not using ARC and then was converted to ARC. I find in certain files, I can use `release` and `autorelease` while in others I can't i.e Xcode gives an error.

I know it is possible to disable ARC for individual files by adding the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for those files in Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. However, none of my files currectly has those flags.

It also looks like `release` has no effect:

```
NSLog(@"Retain count is %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)myObject));
[myObject release];
NSLog(@"Retain count is %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)myObject));
```

In both cases, `NSLog` prints `1`.

Any reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the problem was that I was using an old version of the library `iCarousel` https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel that was non-ARC.

Every file that was importing `iCarousel.h` caused the problem mentioned. I simply downloaded the latest ARC version.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to one of these files:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error "arc yes"
#else
#error "arc no"
#endif
```

Then build.  This will tell you whether ARC is enabled or not (or whether the file is being compiled at all).

If ARC is not enabled and you think it should be, you can use the build log to verify the options passed to the compiler for this file.

Switch to the Report Navigator (Command+8), locate the build error and expand the error by clicking the little hamburger on the right.  This will show all of the options the compiler used for compiling this file.

Copy it into a text editor and search for `-fobjc-arc` and `-fno-objc-arc`, or any other arc-related options.